# Solving ${\log_{\frac{2}{\sqrt{2-\sqrt{3}}}}(x^2-4x-2)=\log_{\frac{1}{2-\sqrt{3}}}(x^2-4x-3)}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This was given to me by my Math Teacher almost a year ago and I've not been able to make much progress on it. I am hoping to see it resolved by our community members. $$\large{\log_{\frac{2}{\sqrt{2-\sqrt{3}}}}(x^2-4x-2)=\log_{\frac{1}{2-\sqrt{3}}}(x^2-4x-3)}.$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

If $x^2-4x-2<0$ or $x^2-4x-3<0$ then the corresponding $x$ cannot be a solution. But forget about that for a second and explain the meaning of the equation below:

$$\log_{\frac{2}{\sqrt{2-\sqrt{3}}}}(x^2-4x-2)=\log_{\frac{1}{2-\sqrt{3}}}(x^2-4x-3).$$

If for an $x$ the equation holds then there must exist some $A$ for which

$$\log_{\frac{2}{\sqrt{2-\sqrt{3}}}}(x^2-4x-2)=A$$

and

$$\log_{\frac{1}{2-\sqrt{3}}}(x^2-4x-3)=A.$$

By the definition of the logarithm one can say that for such an $A$:

$$\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{2-\sqrt{3}}}\right)^A=x^2-4x-2$$

and

$$\left(\frac{1}{2-\sqrt{3}}\right)^A=x^2-4x-3.$$

Or

$$x^2-4x-\left(2+\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{2-\sqrt{3}}}\right)^A\right)=0$$

and

$$x^2-4x-\left(3+\left(\frac{1}{2-\sqrt{3}}\right)^A\right)=0.$$

These are two quadratic equations which can be solved for $x$. The solutions will  depend on the parameter $A$. Since the corresponding solutions  will have to be equal one will have equations for the possible $A$'s.

Given a suitable $A$ an $x$ can be calculated. (Finally test the negativity of the argument of the logarithm.)

Comment: Neat! +1. If we eliminate $x$, we get $(2+\sqrt{3})^A-(2\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}})^A+1=0$. Does that mean there are only "particular values for A" (not just any value)?

Comment: @zoli I have already reached this part. Please give the full answer.

Comment: I can get back to this problem only tomorrw. Sorry.